# Nock not mocking requests on Nextjs and Cypress

Tags: node.js, next.js, mocking, cypress, nock

In some pages, we use getInitialProps that makes a request on the backend side to call an external endpoint. On the CI/CD machine we can´t call this other endpoint so we want to mock that endpoint. **Im trying to centralize the mocked server so I dont need to initialize it on each test that im making and for the future tests.**

Under cypress.config.ts I saw that I can add a [before:run](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api) event under e2e property that I believe will create the endpoint that will intercept all the requests for that endpoint on the tests:

```
on('before:run', async (details) =>
  await nock(/.*?(localhost:4000|{_another_endpoints_regex_here}).*?/)
    .get('/api/')
    .reply(200, {data:"data"})
})
```

I added an regex since the requested url changes between environments, also I have enabled the *experimentalInteractiveRunEvents* flag, I added an console log there and it is showing on console. Also I moved that code inside my page and its working correctly so I believe the issue is not that code.

I wonder why nextjs request its not being mocked? Its an issue related to cypress or nock?

The error that I get is:

```
data: {
      message: 'request to http://localhost:4000/api/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4000',
      type: 'system',
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
    }
```

*If its needed, I can use another framework to mock the requests

---

Update: I have created a new isolated nextjs endpoint and a cypress test to test. Also I tried using [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) and moving the code inside support/e2e.ts in beforeEach hook without success

---

Update 2: So after digging in whole the proyect, I believe the issue is how im executing the tests. Im using [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) package to run the proyect and then execute cypress. I believe this makes two instances of nodejs making cypress and nextjs be on different scope so nock can't be reached by nextjs. How can I execute cypress and nextjs together without using that package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on my OP, looks like I can´t mock backend requests on cypress using nock, msw, or whatever since I believe start-server-and-test create different instances of nodejs, and I believe those mocking tools what does at the end is kind of modify fetch/http methods, but since they run on different instances they dont modify those methods of the instance that is running nextjs.

So afterall, I solved my issue by creating a server that runs on port 4000 with json-server to imitate the server and on nextjs side on .env.development I changed the backend url so it points to the localhost:4000 endpoint and in cypress.config.ts I create the server inside the e2e property inside setupNodeEvents using before:run

```
e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:run', () => {
        //code to create a json-server()
      })
    },
}
```